# playing with two CGRect

Tags: objective-c, cgrect

I have two rectangle R1 and R2

```
---------------------------------
|R1                             |
|                               |
|     ------------------        |
|     |                |        |
|     |  R2            |        |
|     |                |        |
---------------------------------
```

R1 represents the biggest one, and R2 the smallest one. I would like to send the area that we have if we subtract R2 to R1 to my method that takes a rect as input. Is that even possible? Any measure to dodge that

Comment: "I would like to send the area that we have if we subtract R2 to R1 to my method that takes a rect as input."  Subtract R2 to R1?  Huh!?  a rect as input?  You have two rectangles.

Comment: You cannot represent that shape using x+y and w+h.

Comment: shall I represent 3 rectangles and send them one by one?..

Comment: I guess.  You can send all at the same time if you use an array, for example.

Comment: This is nonsense.. sorry to be unhelpful, but you need 8 points..... if you want the area could minus the width x height of R2 from the width x height from R1.. still isn't a 'rect' though

Comment: @Magoo I understood that, but I was more expecting an alternative method to get that area, I know I cannot draw a rect with 8 points

Comment: When you say you want the 'area' do you mean you want the shape representing? or the total number of pixels contained within it?

Comment: @trojanfoe thanks for the tip, was expecting more an answer like yours, what would be the benefits of creating an array, knowing that I can create 3 general `@property (nonatomic, assign) CGRect grabRect;`  and use anything that would send them one by one from wherever I want in my program

Comment: @Magoo The shape so I can feed my grabcut method

Comment: It's much more concise and self-contained and not restricted by the number of properties you provide.

Comment: Is R2 always within the boundaries of R1?

Comment: @laltin Yes, R2 is always within the boundaries of R1

Comment: @alka-hich in that case my answer should work :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find area

```
-(CGSize)areaOfRect:(CGRect)outerRect minusRect:(CGRect)innerRect
{
    return (outerRect.size.width - innerRect.size.width) * (outerRect.size.height - innerRect.size.height);
}
```

Find rects (Assuming these two rects are working from the same bounds)

```
typedef void(^RectCompletion)(CGRect topRect,CGRect leftRect,CGRect rightRect,CGRect bottomRect);


-(void)rectsForRect:(CGRect)outerRect minusRect:(CGRect)innerRect withCompletion:(RectCompletion)completion
{
    // First sanity..
    // You'll need to build up a list of prerequisite checks

    if (innerRect.origin.x < outerRect.origin.x)
        outerRect.origin.x = innerRect.origin.x;

    if (innerRect.origin.y < outerRect.origin.y)
        outerRect.origin.y = innerRect.origin.y;

    if (innerRect.origin.x + innerRect.size.width > outerRect.origin.x + outerRect.size.width)
        NSLog(@"Trim to edge");

    if (innerRect.origin.x > outerRect.origin.x + outerRect.size.width || innerRect.origin.y > outerRect.origin.y + outerRect.size.width)
        NSLog(@"Trim to edge");

    // etc...


    // Assuming the rect is always in bounds below should give you the 4 rects surrounding the inner rect.. 

    // With overlap..

    CGRect topRect = CGRectMake(outerRect.origin.x, outerRect.origin.y, outerRect.size.width, innerRect.origin.y);
    CGRect leftRect = CGRectMake(outerRect.origin.x, outerRect.origin.y, innerRect.origin.x, outerRect.size.height);
    CGRect rightRect = CGRectMake(innerRect.origin.x + innerRect.size.width, outerRect.origin.y, outerRect.size.width - (innerRect.origin.x + innerRect.size.width), outerRect.size.height);
    CGRect bottomRect = CGRectMake(outerRect.origin.x, outerRect.size.height - (innerRect.origin.y + innerRect.size.height), outerRect.size.width, outerRect.size.height - (innerRect.origin.y + innerRect.size.height));


    // No overlap

    CGRect topRect = CGRectMake(outerRect.origin.x, outerRect.origin.y, outerRect.size.width, innerRect.origin.y);
    CGRect leftRect = CGRectMake(outerRect.origin.x, innerRect.origin.y, innerRect.origin.x, innerRect.size.height);
    CGRect rightRect = CGRectMake(innerRect.origin.x + innerRect.size.width, innerRect.origin.y, outerRect.size.width - (innerRect.origin.x + innerRect.size.width), innerRect.size.height);
    CGRect bottomRect = CGRectMake(outerRect.origin.x, outerRect.size.height - (innerRect.origin.y + innerRect.size.height), outerRect.size.width, outerRect.size.height - (innerRect.origin.y + innerRect.size.height));

    completion(topRect,leftRect,rightRect,bottomRect);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to send the area that we have if we subtract R2 to R1 to my method that takes a rect as input. Is that even possible?

No, because an *area* is represented by a *size* (CGSize), but your method takes as input a *rect* (CGRect).

But perhaps when you say "area" you actually mean "shape"? Then you will have to draw or derive the shape yourself. And again, in that case, you cannot send it to a method that "takes a rect as input", because what you will now have will be a *path* (such as a UIBezierPath or CGPath) or else a *drawing* (such as a UIImage).

Thus, as you can see from this screen shot, it is easy to make a cut-out rectangle shape:

[image]

...but the information describing that shape cannot be represented as a mere rect.